# I can't set app restrictions

Tags: android, android-for-work

I'm working with Test DPC app changing its code in order to do some experiments.
I've written a very simple method to set an app restriction, it doesn't throw any exceptions but does not set the restriction's value.
I'm tring to set the restriction 'default_signature' of the gmail app (package name= com.google.android.gm ).
Following the code:

```
Log.d(TAG, "restriction="+restriction);
mDevicePolicyManager.setApplicationRestrictions(
            DeviceAdminReceiver.getComponentName(context),
            (String) message.getExtra("packageName"),
            restriction);
Log.d(TAG, "restriction updated");
```

the log I can see is:

*SetRestrictionAction﹕ restriction=Bundle[{default_signature=test}]*

*SetRestrictionAction﹕ restriction updated*

Anyway this code seems to doesn't affect gmail app.
can anyone explain me where is the problem?
I have a LG G5 H850 device updated to Android 7.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: whats the error you get? stacktrace?

Comment: Hi Opiatefuchs, there are no errors as I reported, I can see both the log rows and all seems to be correct, the problem is that the app (gmail in this case) does not change its behaviour. I hope is clear now. Thanks